# Is L Regular language

Tags: formal-languages

> Prove whether language $a^{(13)^n}$ is regular, or not.

Please, provide the most formal answer as it could be. My teacher is very strict.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you feel like this is regular? Remember that DFA only have a finite amount of memory, and note that the sequence of the $13^n$ is sparser and sparser in $\mathbb N$ as $n$ grows. To prove that a language is not regular, one method is the Pumping lemma.

Comment: you can use Myhill–Nerode theorem ....

Comment: I feel it's not, I'm almost sure, but I need nice, 'formal' solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site! Since you're new here, I should explain that our policy is not to provide complete solutions to what are obviously homework problems, so I'll give you a skeleton proof and leave it to you to provide the meat on the bones.

Call the language $L$. Assume, to the contrary, that $L$ was regular. Then the Pumping Lemma would apply, so let $p$ be the integer of the lemma.

Now consider an integer $n$ such that $13^{n-1}< p\le13^n$. (*Why is there always such an n?*)

Let $s=a^{13^n}$. This string is in $L$. (*Why?*)

So the Pumping Lemma applies and we can write $s=xyz$ with $|xy|\le p\le 13^n$.(*Why?*)

And thus $|xy^2z|\le 2\cdot 13^n$. (*Why?*)

But $2\cdot 13^n<13^{n+1}$. (*Why?*)

And so $xy^2z\notin L$ (*Why?*) and we have a contradiction to the assumption that $L$ was regular. (*Why?*)